# Open file dialog and memory leaks

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks

I'm using this function to open a file in my win32 application:

```
string OpenDialog(HWND hwnd)
{
  OPENFILENAME ofn;
  TCHAR szFile[MAX_PATH];


  ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
  ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
  ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
  ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
  ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
  ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
  ofn.lpstrFilter = TEXT("All files(*.*)\0*.*\0");
  ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
  ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
  ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
  ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
  if(GetOpenFileName(&ofn))
    return ofn.lpstrFile;

}
```

This is quite simple, and I call it using:

```
string path = OpenDialog(hwnd);
```

The problem is that I've found that this function cause a lot of memory leaks!
I'm not 100% sure about what's happening, but everytime that I open a new file using this function, my application become bigger and bigger in RAM.
I'm 100% sure that the cause is this functions, because if I don't load a file using this function, I've stable memory load.

Any hint please ? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your function exhibits undefined behavior if `GetOpenFileName` returns 0.  The reason is that you didn't specify a `return` value if `GetOpenFileName` returns 0.

Comment: Well but, the function still ends in that case, so the garbage collector should still free the memory, right ?

Comment: When you write a function that fails to return a value, the compiler is free to do anything with that function, since the function is technically incomplete. Just add a return statement for when `GetOpenFileName` returns 0, and then retest.  Also, did you test your program with a simple `int main()` function, just to make sure it really is this function causing a problem?

Comment: I've added the return, but the problem still persist.

Comment: Well, please put together a simple main() program that calls your function in a loop.  It should be simple to duplicate if there really is a problem.

Comment: How are you determining that your function is using up this RAM?  What version of Windows are you running?  What compiler (and version of the compiler) are you using?

Comment: OS: Windows 7, COMPILER: GCC 4.7.1 (MinGW), for the RAM, I check it with windows task manager. I'm 100% sure that the leak is in that function because if I don't use it, I get no leaks.

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke the API, windows loads the shell interface & also invokes shell extension handlers. If there is a memory leak introduced by third party shell extension dlls it won't be visible. Also windows does some optimization by keeping references to some of the shell objects for faster loading of the open file dialog on consecutive opens. This may result in increase in memory usage which you will see as memory spike for the first time load.